# spring security xml to property files

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, properties-file

I am trying to add a security layer on my project and I'm doing the following tutorial:
https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-security/login-form-based-spring-3-security-example/

This tutorial use xml files but my config does not.
How can I translate what was written in the xml files (web.xml, application-security.xml) ?

For example the following code:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/employee-servlet.xml
        /WEB-INF/application-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Do I just add something like that to my property file ?

```
context-param.param-name=contextConfigLocation
```

Comment: that tutorial is massively outdated, current spring security version is 5 and the tutorial is using spring security version 3. I would find a better tutorial tbh.

Comment: would this one be more relevant ? https://www.baeldung.com/java-config-spring-security

Comment: i would recommend using the official documentation, baeldungs tutorials can be quite faulty at times because they never get updated, and all comments are turned off on all posts.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-hello

Comment: Alright, thank you for your help, I will see if i close the question after that.